# error when trying to find files in git repo: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/AppleInternal

Tags: python, github, terminal

I am trying to clone and run a project from Github on my computer via the repo's manual instructions listed here:

https://github.com/antoinelame/GazeTracking

i have already done the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/antoinelame/GazeTracking.git
```

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

but when I ran the last line I got the following error: ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt' even though I went and checked and was able to find the file in the repo so I wasn't sure why I was getting the error

in order to troubleshoot, I found most people would run the following line:
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt

but now when I try to run the install requirements.txt line, I get a new error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/python3/python3-103/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl'

can anyone explain what might be causing the error and how I might be able to fix it?

was expecting the install to work so I would be able to run the demo

```
python example.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Open `requirements.txt` and remove the line:

```
six @ file:///AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/python3/python3-103/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```